# How to get random posts in WordPress Heroku

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, heroku

I'm using WordPress Heroku and am trying to display random posts in the sidebar.

I have the following code:

```
                    <h2>Random Posts</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <? $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand' ); 
                        $rand_posts = get_posts( $args ); ?>

                        <? $posts = get_posts($args) ?>
                        <?= $posts === NULL ? "TRUE" : "" .count($posts) ?>
                        <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
```

This code is erroring as follows:

```
[28-Apr-2014 23:56:59 UTC] WordPress database error ERROR:  function rand() does not exist
```

I believe this is because WordPress Heroku does not use MySQL but rather PostgreSQL.

Any ideas on how I can populate $posts with random posts given WordPress Heroku uses PostgreSQL and not MySQL?

Comment: Hi @AnApprentice do you have any tutorial how to install wordpress on heroku or with PostgreSQL. Please help me if you have any tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `posts_orderby` filter to change the `RAND()` part to `RANDOM()`:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'so_23353237_posts_orderby' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

where

```
/**
 * Modify the RAND() of MySQL to RANDOM() for PostgreSQL
 *
 */

function so_23353237_posts_orderby( $orderby )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return ' RANDOM() ';
}
```

Just remember to add the

```
'suppress_filters' => FALSE
```

to the `get_posts()` arguments.

This is untested but you get the idea ;-)